# FXML Doccument refusing to import other fxml files

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have a main FXML document for my program which contains a `TabPane`. For each tab I want it to have its own controller and fxml file. When I try to include the external fmxl files into the main fxml document, my program refuses to run. here is my main FXML document:
here is a copy of my java file

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader fxml = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = fxml.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml").openStream());

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    FXMLDocumentController fdc = fxml.getController();
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Base location is undefined. unknown path:97
```

Comment: What does "refuses to run" mean? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: This line `fx:include source="Tab1.fxml"/>` is missing an angle bracket at the start: `<`

Comment: Missing bracket was a typo. I have inserted the error i get when i try to run it.Thanks

Comment: `Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Base location is undefined.
unknown path:97` Coming from this location. Can you post your controller's code as well?

Comment: Thank you i have uploaded the controller code

Comment: Wondering why the FXML file was deleted from this question at some point. The fact that there is a `<fx:include>` element is pretty important to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is caused because you have not set the `location` property of the `FXMLLoader`, and instead you are specifying an `InputStream` from which to load the FXML. I think the `FXMLLoader` must need to know the location of the original fxml file in order to resolve the location of the included file. You should really only use the `load(InputStream)` method in exceptional circumstances: when you are loading the fxml from a source other than a resource (i.e. file or resource in your application jar file).

Instead, use

```
FXMLLoader fxml = new FXMLLoader();
fxml.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
Parent root = fxml.load();
```

or, equivalently,

```
FXMLLoader fxml = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
Parent root = fxml.load();
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work using an `InputStream` by using the absolute path of the included fxml file  in the fx:include tag.  However, I think changing to use `setLocation` is the better way.