# fx:include when resources are in a different JAR

Tags: javafx-8

I created a framework which opens FXML in other jar files.  I use the following to open them:

(fxml) is a string passed in from a DB query...

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent node = loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fxml).openStream());
```

This works for all my FXML and I really don't want to change this.

I have one new window which will have a very similar implementation with another and I wanted to share the FXML between them with fx:include.

However this throws the error **javafx.fxml.LoadException: Base location is undefined.**

I found this link about [linked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285996/fxml-doccument-refusing-to-import-other-fxml-files)

Is there anyway around this - without changing my entire implementation?  If not, likely will just duplicate the logic.

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to make it work at runtime by using the the full location like this /fxml/location/view.fxml - however then it can't be opened in SceneBuilder

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use the `InputStream` version of `FXMLLoader.load(...)`, as the location will be undefined in the loader (which prevents some functionality being available). Specify the location and call the no-arg `load()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you provide an `InputStream`, the `location` (a `URL`) is undefined. Apparently your FXML is using the location somewhere (e.g. via location resolution) Try

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fxml));
Parent node = loader.load();
```

Comment: Thanks - been using open stream for about 2 years - think I found that here on SO when I first started up.  It worked, so I didn't look any further.